# Cannot understand match in regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match various SQL-like expression in my company's code.

We have two type of INSERT:

1) `InsertInto("TABLE").Values("FIELD_1", "VALUE_1", "FIELD_2", "VALUE_2").Execute()`
in this case we always have an even number of arguments for the `Values` function call

2) `InsertInto("TABLE").Values("FIELD_1", "FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute()`
where in turn `selectExpression` is a variable containing a SELECT query,
here there is not a constraint on number of arguments

I'm using the following regex (**simplified**) to match the `Values` statement of the 1st case:

`Values\(((?<insertfield>"\w+"),\s*(?<insertvalue>(\w|[ .()])+),?\s*)+\)`

Unexpectedly, it also matches a 2nd case **with odd numer of arguments**, like the one above.

https://regex101.com/r/YF5f9i/1

I completely don't understand how that's possible because `"FIELD_1",` seems not being matched at all:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a SQL insert statement using regex?

Comment: That should not be important to answer the question. It could be any type of other string. That said, the goal is to substitute strings (`"FIELD_1"`) with constants (`DbConstants.TABLE.FIELD_1`) in the whole code of an old application. Since now, I successfully matched and substituted near 50.000 occurences.

Comment: At `regex101`, there is a warning displayed on the right, that "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration....". So in your result, your are seeing the second match. Replace `+\)` at the end of your regex with `.*\)` which will show you the first match instead. You'll see that it identifies the empty space behind the first comma as VALUE_1, and hence finds an even number of elements. I guess you don't yet guard well enough against special chars like comma, parantheses, and so on.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Yeah, but my first search started from .NET and there I probably oversight the first capture! Please note that the Regex is really simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches. It just matches another time afterwards. Regex101 only shows the last matches

```
Values\(((?<insertfield>"\w+"),\s*(?<insertvalue>(\w|[ .()])+),?\s*)+\)
```

on `InsertInto("TABLE").Values("FIELD_1", "FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute()`
leads to the core

```
((?<insertfield>"\w+"),\s*(?<insertvalue>(\w|[ .()])+),?\s*)+
```

on `"FIELD_1", "FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute(` (with a `^` in the beginning and `$` in the end if you want to be very clear)

To simplify: `(\w|[ .()])+` is the same as `[\w .()]+`

`((?<insertfield>"\w+"),\s*(?<insertvalue>[\w .()]+),?\s*)+` fits on `"FIELD_1",`(with a space afterwards) as well as `"FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute(`

This means, that the unnamed group(in your example "Group 1") has 2 captures `(?<unnamedGroup>(?<insertfield>"\w+"),\s*(?<insertvalue>[\w .()]+),?\s*)+`

1. `"Field_1",`
2. `"FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute(`

And as Regex102 only displays the last capture, it displays `"FIELD_2", selectExpression).Execute(`

This took me some nerves to find out...

Comment: Yeah, I found the culprit some seconds ago! I was answering my own question! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice that because also .NET parser was showing me only 1 capture of the group, but probably my oversight ;-)

Comment: @Teejay I tried to verify it with .Net as well xD. Was an interesting case

Comment: Adding `(?<!,)` in front of the character class containing the space guarded me from that case. Thanks again.